# How to test an Angular directive using NgZone and Google places?

Tags: angular, google-maps-api-3, karma-jasmine, angular2-directives

I don't find how to test my angular directive...

**google-places.directive.ts**

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, EventEmitter, NgZone, Output } from '@angular/core';
import {} from '@types/googlemaps';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appGooglePlace]'
})
export class AppGooglePlaceDirective {
  @Output() placeChange: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();

  constructor(private el: ElementRef, private ngZone: NgZone) {
    const autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(this.el.nativeElement);
    autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', () => {
      this.ngZone.run(() => {
        const place = autocomplete.getPlace();
        this.placeChange.emit(place);
      });
    });
  }
}
```

**mypage.component.html**

```
<input type="search" appGooglePlace (placeChange)="placeChanged($event)"/>
```

It's working fine in the application but not with ng test and i don 't know how to write it...

I have an error :

> "ReferenceError: google is not defined"

And the the following error in dev console :

> Access to Script at
>   'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=XXXXX&libraries=places'
>   from origin 'http://localhost:9876' has been blocked by CORS policy:
>   No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:9876' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

The first it's the same behavior if i don't import @types/googlemaps in my directive, but i don't know why in test i get this error. Do i need to define typings somewhere in karma/jasmine ??

And for the second, can my spec.ts can call the real google api ? If i want to test the return of "placeChange" ?

This is my attemp of unit test :

**google-places.directive.spec.ts**

```
import { By } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { Component, ElementRef, DebugElement, NgZone } from '@angular/core';
import { AppGooglePlaceDirective } from './google-place.directive';
import {} from '@types/googlemaps';
@Component({
  template: `<input type="search" appGooglePlace (placeChange)="placeChanged($event)" name="test"/>`
})
class TestGooglePlaceComponent {}

export class MockElementRef extends ElementRef {}
export class MockNgZone extends NgZone {
  constructor() {
    super({ enableLongStackTrace: false });
  }
}

fdescribe('GooglePlaceDirective', () => {
  let component: TestGooglePlaceComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<TestGooglePlaceComponent>;
  let zone: NgZone;
  let searchInput: DebugElement;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [TestGooglePlaceComponent, AppGooglePlaceDirective],
      providers: [{ provide: NgZone, useClass: MockNgZone }]
    });

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestGooglePlaceComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    searchInput = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('input[name=test]'));
    zone = new MockNgZone();
  });

  it('should create an instance', () => {
    const directive = new AppGooglePlaceDirective(new MockElementRef(searchInput), zone);
    expect(directive).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Thanks for your help ! I'm really lost to how to write this unit test...

Comment: Found an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Place this under your imports:
declare var google: any;